# C# Serialize list of objects which contains further lists

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a problem with `Xml.Serialization` in C# and hope for help. I have a list of `MyObject` which I want to serialize. The `MyObject` class contains a list of `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint` but I didn't get the list of `MyObject` serialized.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public List<DataPoint> History { get; set; } = new List<DataPoint>();
}
```

I use this code to serialize:

```
List<MyObject> lstObjects;

using (FileStream fileStrm = new FileStream([outputPath], FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyObject>));
    xmlSerial.Serialize(fileStrm, lstObjects);
}
```

But I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` at the list `History`. Did you have any advise for me?

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple example on your given question. I took most of the part from your code as relevant example, except Data point where I implemented in as a list. I was able to serialize XML. Hope this helps.

```
 class Program
{         
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        Details details = new Details();
        details.ID = new Guid();
        details.Name = "testuser";
        details.Status = true;
        details.History = new List<DataPoint>();
        details.History.Add(new DataPoint() {Name = "test"});
        details.History.Add(new DataPoint() { Name = "test1" });
        details.History.Add(new DataPoint() { Name = "test2" });
        details.History.Add(new DataPoint() { Name = "test3" });
        Serialize(details);
        }


private static void Serialize(Details details)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Details));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Xml.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, details);
        }
    }
}

public  class Details
{

    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public List<DataPoint> History { get; set; } = new List<DataPoint>();

}
public class DataPoint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```